# 404 "Not Found" using Nginx for A Express/Node.js App

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu, nginx

I have a node.js application, and I have set up an Nginx reverse proxy server. I can connect to it locally through localhost:8000, but when I attempt to connect to it from an external server while it is running on port 8000 I get a 404 error. I have opened the ufw firewall ports, and the application is running on port:8000, but I cannot connect to it via an external IP. I am using Nginx as a proxy server, and I feel like the configuration file is correct.

Here is my NGINX config file.

```
server {

        server_name subdomain.domain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.com/fullch>
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.domain.com/pr>
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = subdomain.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name subdomain.domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I've changed the actual domain name to subdomain.domain.com have been substituted because of security reasons.

Here is the ufw firewall settings:

```
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] Nginx Full                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] OpenSSH                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 4] 8000:8080/tcp              ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 5] Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 6] OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 7] Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 8] 8000:8080/tcp (v6)         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

If you need any additional details I can provide them.

Comment: you need to connect via `subdomain.domain.com` or `ip:3000`, your app seems to be on `3000` and not `8000`. If not , do change your proxypass to 8000.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Sorry, that was an error it's 8000. I fixed it in the post.

Comment: You can check your /var/log/nginx/access.log and see what's the error there, did it attempt to forward to http://localhost:8000? - how to enable log https://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html

Comment: Also did you put it in sites-enabled ? Did u reload nginx ?

Comment: it definitely seems like your nginx config file is not being loaded. Check if you are including file for that your domain in your ngninx conf. also check with nginx access and error logs for more info.